# How do I add multiple tags for a question (Opera over Android 5)?

Tags: support, bug, tags, editing

I am unable to add more tags in questions I review.
Is their some specific way to add multiple tags in any question?

I mean Existing Tags and less than 5. 
I use my mobile to review under full site mode.

When I directly edit tags or review, both are not working.

I use Opera mini and inbuilt browser of my KitKat.
Edit:Now lollipop.

I go to edit option.
Then I edit question .
 Then I add new tag.

[image]

Then I click on Save edit.

Result: Question is edited but no change in tags.

[image]

It works on Google Chrome where I get a dialog box to select a tag.

Comment: Are you talking about adding existing tags or creating new tags? Also there is a max limit of 5 tags.

Comment: Existing Tags. Less than 5. I use my mobile to review under full site mode.

Comment: Is this from review, or on direct question edit links? Mobile or desktop version? What platform and browser are you running on?

Comment: Direct question edit links and review both.  Opera mini and inbuilt browser of my KitKat.

Comment: This is usually done by adding a space between tags. Is that functionality not working in your case?

Comment: Yeah I tried again but not working.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Please incorporate the information you gave in the comments into your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but it's important to note that *not* every browser is officially supported by Stack Exchange. For a full list see

> [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

on Meta Stack Exchange. As noted there, Opera on mobile is not really officially supported. That means that

> If it's not one of those, it still may work, but you probably shouldn't expect support.

so most of the site should still work, but those little bits of javascriptsy interactingness may or may not work. In particular, [regarding Opera mini](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/184688),

> Unfortunately at the moment we don't support Opera mini.
>
> Reason: a combination of amount of work required and amount of visitors using the browser.

If it works, then excellent. If it doesn't, then there isn't really much that anyone can do, short of convincing the Stack Exchange developer team that Opera Mini really is big enough of a platform to be worth supporting.